# Mysql.ini where can i find it?

Tags: php, mysql

ive installed MySQL but i can't find my.ini. I only have the my-default file in the map.Im trying to configure so that mysql can accept field with default value, but i cant find my.ini :P what should i do

Comment: What OS? Its not going to be in the same place on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that. Windows 7.

Comment: `dir c:\mysql.ini /s /a /p`. eventually it'll tell you where the file is.

Comment: windows key+ E > top left corner, search, type in "Mysql.ini"

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Server on Windows generally gets installed to:

> C:\Program File\MySQL\MySQL Server x.x

The config file is located directly in the root of this directory, even though it may not initially be there.

You may see a file called `my-default.ini`, copy this file to `my.ini` and proceed with edits. When you restart the MySQL Server, it will now find that this file exists, and load from it.

**Edit**

According to the above posted documentation, the server will also look for said file at

> C:\Windows\my.ini